# Apache Ignite OOM Error for Off-Heap persistence storage on Windows 2019

Tags: windows, jvm, out-of-memory, ignite, gridgain

We are getting **OOM** Error while starting the **Ignite** on **Windows 2019 box 64 bit**. We are using off-heap storage of **48GB**. When we reduced the off-heap size to **30 GB** it is working fine. We are using native persistence. The persistence location is default. I checked the diskspace where Ignite is installed and it has free space of more than **100 GB**.

**Ignite Version : 2.8.1**

java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b25)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b25, mixed mode)

Windows Version : 2019 64 Bit, RAM 128 GB and free disk space where we are trying to install is 100 GB

Exception stack trace

```
[2021-02-27 10:42:23,987][ERROR][main][IgniteKernal] Exception during start processors, node will be stopped and close connections
**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError**
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory(Native Method)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe.allocateMemory(GridUnsafe.java:1205)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.mem.unsafe.UnsafeMemoryProvider.nextRegion(UnsafeMemoryProvider.java:103)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager$7.nextRegion(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:1245)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.pagemem.PageMemoryImpl.start(PageMemoryImpl.java:373)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.startCacheGroup(GridCacheProcessor.java:2434)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.getOrCreateCacheGroupContext(GridCacheProcessor.java:2167)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.startCacheInRecoveryMode(GridCacheProcessor.java:2282)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.access$1700(GridCacheProcessor.java:202)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor$CacheRecoveryLifecycle.afterBinaryMemoryRestore(GridCacheProcessor.java:5386)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.restoreBinaryMemory(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:1075)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.startMemoryRestore(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:2049)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1254)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2045)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1703)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1117)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1035)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:921)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:820)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:690)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:659)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:346)
    at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:300)
[2021-02-27 10:42:23,989][ERROR][main][IgniteKernal] Got exception while starting (will rollback startup routine).
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory(Native Method)
```

**Ignite is working on other nodes. Even on other Windows 2019, 2012 box with same configuration.**

Ignite configuration

```
<!-- Redefining maximum memory size for the cluster node usage. -->
<property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
        <!-- Redefining the default region's settings -->
        <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="Default_Region"/>
                <!-- Setting the size of the default region to 48GB. -->
                <property name="maxSize" value="#{48L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                <!-- Enabling RANDOM_2_LRU eviction for this region.  -->
                <property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_2_LRU"/>
                <!-- Enabling persistence for this region.  -->
                <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <!-- set the size of wal segments to 512 MB -->
        <!-- the default 64 MB could not store large single position entry and caused error-->
        <property name="walSegmentSize" value="#{512 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
        <!-- Keep WALs Separately  -->
        <property name="walPath" value="D:\am-bmt-ignite-wal\wal"/>
        <property name="walArchivePath" value="D:\am-bmt-ignite-wal\archive"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Is there any configuration related to Windows box which we can check?

I saw a similar issue in Ignite group :
http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/After-increasing-maxsize-in-DataRegionConfiguration-Ignite-throws-out-of-memory-exception-td30907.html

Let me know if anyone has faced this kind of issue.

Comment: Have you checked that you are using 64-bit JVM? Here, OS says it can't allocate memory to JVM. Maybe some kind of OS limit is configured.

Comment: yes i check the JVM, it's 64 bit.

Comment: I think it's more of a Windows issue then. Are you sure that this box actually has 128G RAM?